# Django Faking Required Fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'd like to know if there's any to way to make a nullable (`null=True`) field be required when creating models (or saving)?

As a superuser, I'd like to be able to leave certain fields with null while other staff members won't be able to.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

I have this exact `__init__` for both `StudentChangeForm` and `StudentCreationForm`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(StudentCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # StudentChangeForm in StudentChangeForm (obviously)

    if self.user.is_superuser:
        self.fields['picture'].required = False
```

I also have a `StudentAdmin` class which represents the `Student` model in my admin:

```
class StudentAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = StudentChangeForm
    add_form = StudentCreationForm

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Student

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'user': request.user})
        # What's supposed to be here?
```

I tried already so many variations in `get_form` and can't seem to get the right one.

Sorry for troubling you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can do that, and it comes in handy when there is information which would relate to the user, that you wouldn't know yourself when needing to create objects.

So, to do so you simply create your own form and declare the field in the form as required. You can then run your validation on the form before creating the object.

For example, here's a form I've got which is used by the model admin;

```
class EventAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label=_("State/Province/Territory"),
        queryset=Category.objects.none(),
        empty_label=_("---------"),
        required=False,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(EventAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['category'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ()
```

Just like any other form, you can define your fields, and whether or not they are required.

So, following the update, you need to pass the user to the form. For example;

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventAdminForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do something with the data
            pass
    else:
        form = EventAdminForm(user=request.user)
```

If you've got a form, but want to know if you're editing an object, or creating one it's quite simple. If you're editing, the form will have an instance attribute which is the object you're editing.

`get_from()` takes an `obj` argument which is likely the object, if you're editing one, but you'd have to check that. Docs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form

**Edit**

Ok, lets simplify this, and put the required logic in admin, then you don't need to mess with the form at all;

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    if request.user.is_superuser:
        form.base_fields['picture'].required = False

    return form
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you please edit your answer so that `required` will be `True` only if `not user.is_superuser`? I'm just trying to understand where to put it...

Comment: How is the view `someview` relevant? What should I do with it?

Comment: @AnDrOiD well the form requires a request object to get the user, so if you weren't doing this with an admin form, that's how you'd use it in a view.

Comment: Do I still need the view if I use the form only in the admin?

Comment: @AnDrOiD no, you don't have views in admin, so you need to override `get_form()` so that you can provide the request to the form.

Comment: How do I determine inside weather I need to use `StudentChangeForm` or `StudentCreationForm`?

Comment: @AnDrOiD I've updated my answer. You can probably check for the `obj` argument in `get_form()` and if it's there, use your change form, if it's not, your creation form.

Comment: I get an error at this line: `form = super(EventAdminForm, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)`, which basically says that the 2nd parameter of `super` has to be an instance or subtype of the 1st parameter, of `EventAdminForm`.

Comment: Yeah, you're not matching the function signature. Pass obj to the super.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129878/discussion-between-markwalker-and-android).